# Check if a file exists in scene file, if yes invoke error else force open the file

Tags: python, maya

I have a code that performs the following:

1. opens a rigfile,  target rig file
2. creates a Hik node and hooks the mocap joints of the rig file to the character def
3. imports a mocap file (source rig) and creates another hik node for
   the source joints to map the character def
4. mocap data transferred from source to target
5. target joints are baked and source rig data is deleted.

I wish to keep my  target rig file in the scene and continue procs 3-5. 
I need to query if the target rig file exits, if yes then skip procs 1 and 2 and continue 3-5, else start over from 1 to 5.

How do i check if the rig file already exists in the scene?
P.s: I have just started off with coding in python in maya :)

Answer (score 1):

For checking existence of file, use **os.path.exists**.
scene is your directory which is e.g. "M:/Desktop" below.

```
import os

if os.path.exists("M:/Desktop/rigfile.txt"):
    # Perform statements 3-5
else:
    # Perform statements 1-5
```

Comment: This checks the existence of the file on disk, not in the scene.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is meant by the "scene"? Perhaps by showing some example code, so we will know what that is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a file exists:

```
import os
if os.path.exists("FULL/PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE.ma"):
    # Do code
```

If you want to check if a specific object exists in the scene:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
if cmds.objExists("YOUR_OBJECT_NAME"):
    # Do code
```